# Socket.io bug after success request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Guys!
Expected some bug with my socket.io.
So, all work fine. Below you can see the code example:

Server (Node.js):

controller:

```
.put('/user', jwtMiddleware, (req, res, next) => userService.updateUser(req.user.id, req.body.imageId, req.body)
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message); <------ LOOK AT THIS (1)
      req.io.to(req.user.id).emit('user_data', err.message); // notify a user if username or email isn't unique
      res.status(400).send();
      next();
    }));
```

P.S. io injected to the request object.

userService.updateUser.js:

```
export const updateUser = async (userId, imageId, user) => {
  const userByName = await userRepository.getByUsername(user.username);

  if (userByName !== null && userByName.id !== userId) {
    throw new Error('Username should be unique');
  }

  const { id } = await userRepository.updateById(userId, {
    ...user,
    imageId
  });
  return getUserById(id);
};
```

Below you can see client code (React.js):

```
socket.on('user_data', message => {
   console.log(message); <----- LOOK AT THIS (2)
   NotificationManager.info(message);
});
```

And now time for explaining the problem.

a) When I send my user object from client to controller with 'username' that has already existed in the DB, I wonderful receive response on the client and my socket on the client in the places (1) (2) well work.

b) But when I send my user object from the client to the controller with 'username' that doesn't exist in the DB, it will fine save in the DB and after that, if I send a request as in point (a), I won't receive a response on the client. My socket on the server in a place (1) WORK CORRECTLY and in a place (2) ISN'T WORK.

Why has it happened?

Comment: How do you expect `req.io.to(req.user.id)` to work properly if this request does not have a correct user ID in the first place?  How could `req.user.id` be correct if `userService.udpateUser(req.user.id, ...)` failed? It seems that errors should go back in the response to the PUT request, not over socket.io.

Comment: 1. Io injected to request.
2. By passport strategy user injected to request and all work correctly and every time my request has userId. In place (1) reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

These are the reasons I can think of why you wouldn't receive the message from when you do this:

```
req.io.to(req.user.id).emit('user_data', err.message);
```

1. `req.user` or `req.user.id` is not what you expect it to be and thus `req.io.to(req.user.id)` doesn't find a valid user connection to send to.
2. The target page does not yet have an appropriate socket.io connection with the selected `id` value
3. When the request receives back the 400 status, it is not then in a state where it can receive your socket.io message (we'd have to see the client-side code to comment more on that).  For example, if it reloads the page, then that old socket.io connection would be torn down and a new one with a different `socket.id` would be created.

FYI, you can step into `req.io.to(req.user.id)` in the debugger and see exactly how many matching socket.io connections it finds.

---

Also, FYI, you should not be called `next()` after doing `res.status(400).send();`.  That will probably generate a warning as you will end up trying to send two responses to the same request.  Remove the call to `next()`.

Comment: @sergeychyzhyk - Did this help you figure things out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because in the success response you're not emitting any socket event.

```
.put('/user', jwtMiddleware, (req, res, next) => userService.updateUser(req.user.id, req.body.imageId, req.body)
    .then(data => {
      req.io.to(req.user.id).emit('user_data', 'User Created Successfully')
      res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message); <------ LOOK AT THIS (1)
      req.io.to(req.user.id).emit('user_data', err.message); // notify a user if username or email isn't unique
      res.status(400).send();
      next();
    }));
```

Comment: Sir, you didn't understand my problem.

Comment: In catch block in the second time req.io.to(req.user.id).emit('user_data', err.message); won't call.